# Cocos2d js onTouch doesn't recognize local variables

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I have this problem with an `onTouchBegin` function in which I want to update the position of a sprite on screen. However if I use this line of code inside of the update function is works flawlessly.

```
this.sprite.x += 5;
```

Now if I put this line of code inside the `onTouchBegin` or any `onTouch` method I receive this error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"`.

When I debug this inside the chrome console the local variables to the current `js` file exist and are shown as being instantiated variables with all properties and attributes attached. Then when I click the screen the debugger pauses inside the `onTouchBegin` function. At this point all the variables seem to be outta scope because they all show up as `undefined` or `NaN` or something else.

I cannot figure why this happening if anyone can give me some insight on how to fix this that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently in the callback function when the callback is returned the event parameter has some attributes attached to it one of the being called getCurrentTarget. This returned the js file that contained all the variables that were properly being used in the update function.
  
    `onTouchBegan:function(touch, event) 
    {
        var target = event.getCurrentTarget();
    },`